# How to set constraints in Collection View and inside Cells in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint

I am displaying name and image in `UICollectionView`.I have set constraints in `iPhone SE` device but not set in `iPhone Plus` device and `iPhone X`.How can i fix in constraints with all devices.

Comment: Plz explain more about the issue and also share screenshot if possible.

Comment: Constrains are set in such way that application UI will look fine in all iphone. This is the wrong way to do to set constrain for particular iPhone. Please go through the basics of constrains.

Answer (score 0):

set the Constraints via Code or in your .swift file not in .nib , maybe that will help you out for that just turn transletAutoResizingMasks = false

or just keep on setting constraints via nib file one day you will master it cz setting up the constraints via nib is easy but needs one to have hand on it , 
just watch LetsbuildThatApp channel by brain Voong on youtube , do his projects follow his tutorials

you will be able to set up constraints without .nib file

thanks :)